# Handle constructors in Java Springboot framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on the following code where I have two java files A.java and m.java. Code is as follows and I am going into a cycle because of the above code change. I tried to remove the cycle by using @inject for A class object in m.java but it gives me null exception when doing _a.doSomething().

Code is as follows:
A.java

```
class A {

    A(x,y,z,m){
    /* do the necessary initialization */
    }

    A (x, y, z){
    this(x,y,z,m(new A(x,y,z)))
    }
}
```

m.java

```
class m {
    _a
    public m(A a){
     _a = a;
    }

    public void func(){
        _a.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Please suggest how can I handle such scenario.

Comment: If `A` and `m` are beans, the [Autowired annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire) may be helpful.

Comment: A is a bean but not m.

Answer (score 0):

Cycle is caused by second `A` constructor. Let's analyze it:

```
class A {

    A(x,y,z,m){
        /* do the necessary initialization */
    }

    A (x, y, z){
        this(x,y,z,m(new A(x,y,z)))
    }
}
```

On second constructor, you have three params, and the unique line indicates a call to first constructor, with a new `m` instance. But the problem is this instance calls second constructor again, so you execute the same again: the unique line calls first constructor, with a new `m` instance that calls second constructor... and so on. Then, this execution will be interrupted by a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` exception. I suggest you must only use first constructor and remove the second one.

Comment: And after removing second constructor, how will I be able to cal the doSomething() function?

Comment: With a getter method to `m` instance on `A` class. So, you can invoke with `a.getM().func()`